# How write a .txt file in c# using StreamReader in Metro App?

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I'm having trouble creating a StreamReader object in Windows 8 metro application. I'm trying to make it read the text file in my local directory but it keep showing me this error. Anyone has any solutions for this or any other alternative solutions?

I'm using MS Visual Studio Ultimate 2012, metro application.

Code:

```
        int level = 1;

        var fileName = string.Format(@"Mazes\level{0}.txt", level);

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            var l = 0;
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();

                for (var c = 0; c < line.Length; c++)
                {
                    mazeValues[c, l] = line[c];

                    if (mazeValues[c, l] == '1')
                    {
                        var glass = new Glass();
                        glass.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, c);
                        glass.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, l);
                        grdMaze.Children.Add(glass);
                        mazeGlasses[c, l] = glass;
                    }
                }
                l++;
            }
        }
```

Error showing:

> The best overloaded method for
>   'System.IO.StreamReader.StreamReader(System.IO.Stream)' has some
>   invalid arguements.

Comment: Where is the filepath pointing `@"Mazes\level{0}.txt`? Is that a mapped drive or something?

Comment: use streamwriter to write ..

Comment: @JeremyThompson its pointing inside the project, one of the folders named 'Mazes'

Comment: @matzone I'm creating mazes in a .txt file.I was told that StreamReader is able to read the file :/

Comment: If you look at the [documentation for `StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) you will notice that the Windows Store Applications do not support reading a stream from a path in a string format.

Comment: @MarkHall Hi Mark, is there any other way of doing it? :/

Answer (score 1):

[Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefromapplicationuriasync%28v=win.10%29.aspx) and [Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.readlinesasync.aspx) can be used for this.

```
using System;
using Windows.Storage;
async void test2()
{

    var fileName = string.Format(@"ms-appx:///Mazes/level{0}.txt", level);
    try 
    {
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri( "ms-appx:///assets/textfile1.txt"));
        var lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            // code to process each line here
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         // handle exceptions
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sushil, I've put up the codes area where I've been facing some problems.. I've tried your method but I'm not quite sure how to apply it :/

Answer (score 0):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();       
System.IO.Stream stream = client.OpenRead(path_of_text _file);
     System.IO.StreamReader str = new StreamReader(stream);
     string Text = str.ReadLine();

   while (!Text.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = Text.ReadLine();

            for (var c = 0; c < line.Length; c++)
            {
                mazeValues[c, l] = line[c];

                if (mazeValues[c, l] == '1')
                {
                    var glass = new Glass();
                    glass.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, c);
                    glass.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, l);
                    grdMaze.Children.Add(glass);
                    mazeGlasses[c, l] = glass;
                }
            }
            l++;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, the error says that 'client' does not exist in the content :/

Comment: i think you haven't added the namespace for it...please check by adding name space.....
use namespace  
using System.Net;   
hope this will work for oyu now..

Comment: Hi Sanjeev, I've added the namespace you've given but the same error is still there :/